# Can PHP retrieve data from Firebase / Firestore?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a PHP library for connecting php to the Firebase Firestore database?
Is it even possible to PHP to retrieve data from Firebase?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes, i think this is what i needed. I will have a look in more detail soon

Comment: See [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start)

Comment: @Kato I have started working with the Firestore database already. Am I able to do email and password authentication with PHP?  If not, can document data be retrieved with PHP? Everything that I have seen so far point to a no, but I'm somehow still hopeful there might be a way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is now a [PHP client library](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/master/firestore/firestoreclient).

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$db = new FirestoreClient();

$citiesRef = $db->collection('cities');
$query = $citiesRef->where('state', '=', 'CA');
$snapshot = $query->documents();
foreach ($snapshot as $document) {
    printf('Document %s returned by query state=CA' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
}
```

You'll find more examples in our [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) now, just select the PHP tab on the snippets.

Comment: But how to display each values in web page ie. html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can retrieve data using PHP, an example:

```
$db->getReference('people')
->orderByChild('height')
->getSnapshot();
```

The above will order the reference's children by the values in the field 'height' in ascending order.

more info here:

http://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/realtime-database.html

https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php

Comment: This is all related to the Realtime Database and not Cloud Firestore, which is what I'm after (as it is to do with a existing Cloud Firestore project)