# how to deploy web application on firebase?

Tags: laravel, firebase, web-applications, firebase-hosting

i am new in this field so i dnot know how to deploy my site in to firebase i tried different method to deploy but it will show this screen every time http://prntscr.com/pennbc
what is the best way to deploy my web app to firebase hosting...

The application has a few system requirements, so you will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:
`1.Laravel 5.5+
2.PHP 7.1.3+,
3.MySQL 5.7+
4.Intl PHP Extension
5.OpenSSL PHP Extension
6.PDO PHP Extension
7.Mbstring PHP Extension
8.Tokenizer PHP Extension
9.XML PHP Extension
10.Ctype PHP Extension
11.JSON PHP Extension
12.cURL PHP Extension
13.GD PHP Extension
14.ZIP PHP Extension`

this is my directory folder
http://prntscr.com/penoe2

i have tried these method 
http://prntscr.com/penraf
http://prntscr.com/pensi9

Comment: Firebase doesn’t support PHP, or any server-side languages.

Comment: is there any solution ?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Perhaps this? [Can PHP retrieve data from Firebase / Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226283/can-php-retrieve-data-from-firebase-firestore) and the associated library [Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/master/firestore/firestoreclient)

Comment: Firebase is a suite of hosting tools for mobile applications; it does not host web applications likes ones built with php/laravel. For that, look into a web host like Linode, DigitalOcean or AWS. Laravel's Forge service can help you provision and deploy to one of those.